# Is Redux unidirectional?

Tags: reactjs, flux, redux

After implementing Flux, it was easy to see that it is in fact unidirectional.

Flux recap: The View takes in user actions, which get sent to and interpreted by Action Creators, which get sent to the Dispatcher, which get broadcast to the Stores, which eventually trigger an update back in the View.

With Redux, although I've only read a handful of blog posts on it, it seems as though the Action Creators are in fact returning the formatted action object back to the View that fired off the action in the first place.

See: https://code-cartoons.com/a-cartoon-intro-to-redux-3afb775501a6#.3hquuzljm

So the question is this: Does having the Action Creator by design return to the View disrupt the very notion of uni-directional workflow?

I haven't implemented Redux just yet, so perhaps I'm missing a step, but this sticks out to me as a big difference between Flux and Redux.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're putting too much emphasis on what action creators are.

An action creator is literally just this:

```
function login(username, password) {
  return { type: 'LOGIN', payload: { username, password };
}
```

These two things are identical:

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  ...
  render() {
    const { username, password } = this.props;

    return (
      ...
        dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN', payload: { username, password });
        // or
        dispatch(login(username, password));
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

And then if you user `react-redux`'s `connect`, it can look like

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  ...
  render() {
    const { username, password } = this.props;

    return (
      ...
        login(username, password)); // connect binds the AC to dispatch for convenience.
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

Action creators are not a large abstraction. they're just a special name for a function that helps makes actions to keep your code DRY. They don't do anything to change the unidirectional model.

Comment: Exactly my point. In Flux, the ActionCreator calls the dispatcher instead of  returning the action object to the View that fired it off. This makes it easy to see the unidirectional workflow.


Now, Redux is returning the action object back to the View, where it gets dispatched to the Store. The mere fact that it gets returned to the View would seem to disrupt a unidirectional workflow.

Comment: You're entitled to your opinion, but wouldn't expect to find many people who agree with you. The original FB spec on flux says action creators return actions which are dispatched. This is exactly what redux is doing. If that is not unidirectional then flux is not undirectional. https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/07/30/flux-actions-and-the-dispatcher.html

Comment: If somehow you're uncomfortable with doing it this way, `react-redux` provides `connect` which allows you to bind action creators with `dispatch` to save on syntax. I don't think it has any material effect on whether its unidirectional or not.

Answer (score 0):

The data flow in Flux and Redux is pretty much the same, you just don't have the Dispatcher and callbacks, because the actions operate on store. (Compare it with [this flux diagram](http://blog.krawaller.se/img/flux-diagram.png).)

The Redux documentation has [a great chapter on this topic](http://rackt.org/redux/docs/basics/DataFlow.html):

> Redux architecture revolves around a **strict unidirectional data
> flow**.
>
> This means that all data in an application follows the same lifecycle
> pattern, making the logic of your app more predictable and easier to
> understand. It also encourages data normalization, so that you don't
> end up with multiple, independent copies of the same data that are
> unaware of one another.
>
> If you're still not convinced, read
> Motivation and [The Case for
> Flux](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/the-case-for-flux-379b7d1982c6)
> for a compelling argument in favor of unidirectional data flow.
> Although [Redux is not exactly Flux](http://rackt.org/redux/docs/introduction/PriorArt.html), it
> shares the same key benefits.
>
> The data lifecycle in any Redux app follows these 4 steps:
>
> 1. You call `store.dispatch(action)`.
> 2. The Redux store calls the reducer function you gave it.
> 3. The root reducer may combine the output of multiple reducers into a single state tree.
> 4. The Redux store saves the complete state tree returned by the root reducer.

Answer (score 0):

> Does having the Action Creator by design return to the View disrupt the very notion of uni-directional workflow?

## TLDR:

The action creator in redux returns the action without calling dispatch. Correct. 
Does this break unidirectional workflow? No.

After receiving the action from the action creator, it can be forwarded to the store by calling the dispatch() function with the returned action as parameter. Thus the data flow is still unidirectional.

## Details:

### 1

In traditional Flux implementations, action creators often trigger a dispatch when invoked, like so:

```
function addTodoWithDispatch(text) {
  const action = {
    type: ADD_TODO,
    text
  }
  dispatch(action)
}
```

By contrast, in Redux action creators are pure functions with zero side-effects. They simply return an action:

```
function addTodo(text) {
  return {
    type: ADD_TODO,
    text
  }
}
```

This makes them more portable and easier to test. To actually initiate a dispatch, pass the result to the dispatch() function:

```
dispatch(addTodo(text))
dispatch(completeTodo(index))
```

http://rackt.org/redux/docs/basics/Actions.html

### 2

As shown in https://code-cartoons.com/a-cartoon-intro-to-redux-3afb775501a6#.e9br039va

1. The view requests an action. The action creator formats it and returns it.
2. The action is either dispatched automatically (if bindActionCreators() was used in setup), or the view dispatches the action.
3. The store receives the action.

So therefore the dataflow is still unidirectional.